# How to get the file count from a loop process to count in a content section outside of the loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, counter

I am stuck. You will see I have var *$file_count_header*. I am simply trying to get this to increase in number along with the same counts as *$file_count* (ideally just use the same variable). *$file_count* is increased as expected in the if()  But as you can see my header content is not in the loop. I attempted several resolutions by putting the entire code in another loop, but I could not get it to work still.

```
$results_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

$i = 0;
$file_count = 1;
$per_file = 100;
$footer = 'FOOTER';
$default_contents = $contents = array("HEADER . $file_count_header");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Build the line contents here
    $line = $row['id'];
    $contents[] = $line; // Each array element will be a line in the text file
    $i++;
    // Every $per_file number of records, write the contents to the file and start counting over
    if ($i == $per_file) {
        $contents[] = $footer; // Add the footer to the end
        file_put_contents($results_count .'-'. $file_count .'.txt', implode("\r\n",  $contents));
        // Reset the counter and set the contents to the 
        $i = 0;
        $contents = $default_contents;
        $file_count++;
        $file_count_header++;
    }
}
// Output the rest of the contents to the last file
$contents[] = $footer; // Add the footer to the end
file_put_contents($results_count .'-'. $file_count .'.txt', implode("\r\n",     $contents));
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize

```
$file_count_header = 1;
```

at the top with `$file_count` like

```
$file_count = 1;
$file_count_header = 1
```

You got a problem because you have not initialize `$file_count_header` and even it is only used in `if` within `while`. So it should be declared outside `while` with default value.

Comment: I should have noted I did attempt this too, but it did not work. Same result. Count does not change. For example if I initialize $file_count_header = 1; it will be 1 in all headers no count difference.

Comment: It should. Can you update your code with change I said. If `$file_count` get increased then `$file_count_header` must also be increased. and can you show output of variables which you used or use `var_dump($file_count_header);` after loop completes.

Comment: You are correct, but $default_contents = $contents = array("HEADER . $file_count_header"); is not being updated with the proper count on each iteration because it is loaded prior and not changed during the looping.

Comment: Do you get value of `$file_count_header` before `$default_contents = $contents = array("HEADER . $file_count_header");` line? If yes then show here `var_dump($file_count_header);` value;

Comment: Ok. Also try to put in loop after you incrementing value of `$file_count_header++;` like `echo "in loop:";var_dump($file_count_header);echo "<br/>";` Then you can see what exactly happening. Because if you declare `$file_count_header` at top of your code then it must be accessible in loop and outside loop.